# iterating over subpaths vs path elements

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

The question **applies to any neo4j path**, but for clarity, let's borrow the bus route data from Answer 2 to this post

[Neo4J | Cypher Aggregation on list of relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011627/neo4j-cypher-aggregation-on-list-of-relationships)

We can run this query

```
MATCH p=(o:BusStop)-[*]->(d:BusStop) RETURN p
```

and get a bunch of Nodes and Relationships, as we would expect.

> p [ {   "id": 1 } , {   "fare": 10,   "day": "Sat" }... and so on

My problem with the above is that when processing the results in Python, I'm forced to iterate over individual Nodes and Relationships.

**But what if I wanted to iterate over complete (startnode)-[*]-(endnode)** sub-paths?

In the browser, individual subpaths are separated by horizontal lines. How do I get an equivalent to those separators in py2neo?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neo4j results are a stream of records. For the given query, each record in the stream will be a separate path, so you would use the methods of the [returned results cursor](https://py2neo.org/v3/database.html#cursors) to iterate over each path.

If you wanted a single result that was a collection of paths, you could return that instead:

```
RETURN collect(p) as results
```

Comment: Got it. My mistake was to dump everything into a list with cursor.data() right away - that's how I lost the separators.